# Wrong values with np.mean()?

Tags: python, image, numpy, mean

I'm quite new to programming (in Python) and so I don't understand what is going on here. I have an image (35x64) as a 3D-array and with np.mean(), I attempted to extract the mean of one color channel of one row:

```
print(np.mean(img[30][:][0]))
```

For comparison, I also wrote a for-loop to append the exact same values in a list and calculating the mean with that:

```
for i in range(64):
    img_list.append(img[30][i][0])
print(np.mean(img_list))
```

Now, for a strange reason, it gives different values:

```
First output: 117.1
Second output: 65.7
```

By looking at the list, I discovered that the second one is correct. Can somebody with more experience explain to me why this is exactly happening and how to fix that? I don't want to use the second, longer code chunk in my programs but am searching for a 1-line solution that gives a correct value.

Comment: Can you make sure your `img.shape` is `(35, 64, _)`

Comment: @sshashank124 It is.

Comment: Yes I saw the answer below. Glad it was resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between `img[30][:][0]` and `img[30,:,0]` (the one you were expecting). 
Let's see with an example:

```
img = np.arange(35*64*3).reshape(35,64,3)
img[30][:][0]
# array([5760, 5761, 5762])
img[30,:,0]
# array([5760, 5763, ... 5946, 5949])
```

So you simply need to:

```
print(np.mean(img[30,:,0]))
```

(which is more efficient anyways).

Some details: in your original syntax, the `[:]` is actually just triggering a copy of the array:

```
xx = img[30]
yy = img[30][:]
print (xx is yy, xx.shape, yy.shape, np.all(xx==yy))
# False (64, 3) (64, 3) True # i.e. both array are equal
```

So when you take `img[30][:][0]`, you're actually getting the 3 colors of the first pixel of row 30.